# Read 16-bit PNG using libpng

Tags: c++, libpng, 16-bit

I need to read 16 bit png images in C++ with libpng.

I got the code working for 8 bit, however I can't find a solution to get it working for 16 bit PNGs.

A code snippet for reading 8 bit looks basically like this (adopted from [here](https://gist.github.com/niw/5963798)):

```
png_byte color_type;
png_byte bit_depth;
png_bytep *row_pointers;
int rowbytes = png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr);

row_pointers = (png_bytep*)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);
for (int y = 0; y<height; y++)
    row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr));

png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);
```

If I use that code, the 16-bit image is read incorrectly. I think this happens because `png_bytep` contains just 8-bit values.

Therefore, I tried to declare the row pointers as `png_uint_16` by replacing `png_bytep` with `png_uint16p`. The code snippet from above would look like this:

```
png_byte color_type;
png_byte bit_depth;
png_uint_16p *row_pointers;
int rowbytes = png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr);

row_pointers = (png_uint_16p*)malloc(sizeof(png_uint_16p) * height);
for (int y = 0; y<height; y++)
    row_pointers[y] = (png_uint_16*)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr));

png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);
```

However, the problem is that the function `png_read_image` requires a `png_bytep` as input, which is to my knowledge only 8-bit. But is there really no way to read an 16-bit image with libpng?

Comment: I believe you have to access the raw data byte-wise and build the 16 bit values by bit-shifting. I was uncertain about endianess (which, configurable?) and looked for doc. - The "official" doc says _PNG files store 16 bit pixels in network byte order (big-endian, ie. most significant bits first)._ So, I assume this is what you have to consider in low-level reading. Doc.: [libpng version 1.2.5 - III. Reading](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-3). (You will find newer docs on http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/ as well.)

Comment: Have you tried casting `png_ptr` to `png_bytep`?

Comment: @ scheff: ok I'll read through that and see if I find a solution.
@ Mark: `png_ptr` is defined as `png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct`, casting it differently doesn't work. Thx for your answers